# Станция метро «Проспект Просвещения» / «проспект Просвещения»

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, кавычки, топонимика

Как правильно?

1. Я готова пойти на уступки в связи с такой задержкой и приехать к метро «Проспект Просвещения».
2. Я готова пойти на уступки в связи с такой задержкой и приехать к метро «проспект Просвещения».
3. Я готова пойти на уступки в связи с такой задержкой и приехать к метро Проспект Просвещения.
4. Я готова пойти на уступки в связи с такой задержкой и приехать к метро проспект Просвещения.

Comment: Если топоним, то площадь Восстания.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Довольно исчерпывающе на подобный вопрос ответила «Грамота.ру» (см. [здесь](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=201162)).

**Вопрос № 201162**

> как писать названия улиц и станций метро? Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> В названиях улиц, площадей, проспектов, бульваров и т. п. с большой
> буквы пишутся все слова, кроме родовых наименований (т. е. самих слов
> *улица, площадь, проспект*) и слов *года, лет*. Правильно: *Невский проспект, площадь Восстания, Таврическая улица, Большая Морская улица*
> и т. п. Названия станций метро пишутся в кавычках, с большой буквы
> пишется первое слово названия, а также все слова, которые пишутся с
> большой буквы в составе соответствующих топонимов. Например: *станции
> метро «Лиговский проспект», «Технологический институт», «Площадь
> Восстания», «Площадь Александра Невского»*.

Получается, верен 1-й вариант.

*Я готова пойти на уступки в связи с такой задержкой и приехать к метро **«Проспект Просвещения»**.*